# Find element in array with lowest difference from average in C

Tags: c, arrays, average

I need to set the size of array. After that I start to input numbers to dill this array. During that procedure I count sum for calculating average later.

Now I have an array and average and I need to find the element with lowest difference from average.

Like:
`array size = 3`
`input = 1`
`input = 2`
`input = 3`

`average = 2`

Counting

`abs( 1 - 2 ) = 1`
`abs( 2 - 2 ) = 0`
`abs( 3 - 2 ) = 1`

So the lowest difference have the element with value `2`. And in the end of the program I need to out put that element from array and its index.

So far I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    int n = 0, i = 0;

    double average = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double tmp = 0;

    double min = 0;
    int index = 0;

    int *a;
    double *b;

    printf("Amount of elements = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if( 0 == n )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if( n < 1 || n > 10 )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    a = ( int* )malloc( sizeof( *a ) * n );
    b = ( double* )malloc( sizeof( *b ) * n );

    while( i < n )
    {
        printf("Input number: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        sum += a[i];
        i++;
    }

    average = ( double )( sum / n );

    printf("Average = %.3lf\n", average);

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        tmp = abs( ( double )( a[ i ] ) - average );
        b[ i ] = tmp;
    }

    /* for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {

    } */

    free( a );
    free( b );

    return 0;

}
```

**Update:** My apologies. The question is how to achive the last part  without macking this simple program even more complicated.

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the 2 variables defined to hold the lowest difference and index of the lowest difference in something like

```
    min = b[0]; /* initialize min with b[0] */
    index = 0;  /* and index with 0 */
    for( i = 1; i < n; i++ ) /* loop from 1 onwards ... index 0 was used for initialization */
    {

        /* maybe change min to b[i] */
        /* and index to i */

    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
```

Comment: But I need to find smallest difference, not the smallest value. Something like: `for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { tmp = abs( ( double )( a[ i ] ) - average ); b[ i ] = tmp; }`

Comment: @Eugene: the `b` array already holds the differences when you get to this loop. Just loop through the array checking if the value (which is the difference!) is the lowest so far and update the variables.